# webform email field autocomplete

Tags: 7, webforms, ajax

I can quite easily add ajax autocomplete properties to a regular textfield using the code below, but it doesn't work when I change the field to type `webform_email`. Is it possible to do?

```
function flower_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_68911') {
        //Add autocomplete fields for manager username
        $form['submitted']['name_of_authorising_manager']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';  
    }
}
```

Here's the dpr output for the relevant field in the form:

```
Array
(
    [#type] =&gt; webform_email
    [#title] =&gt; Name of authorising manager:
    [#title_display] =&gt; inline
    [#default_value] =&gt; 
    [#required] =&gt; 1
    [#weight] =&gt; 4
    [#description] =&gt; 
    [#attributes] =&gt; Array
        (
            [class] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; email
                )

        )

    [#element_validate] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; _webform_validate_email
        )

    [#theme_wrappers] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; webform_element
        )

    [#translatable] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; title
            [1] =&gt; description
        )

    [#webform_component] =&gt; Array
        (
            [nid] =&gt; 68911
            [cid] =&gt; 18
            [pid] =&gt; 0
            [form_key] =&gt; name_of_authorising_manager
            [name] =&gt; Name of authorising manager:
            [type] =&gt; email
            [value] =&gt; 
            [extra] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [title_display] =&gt; inline
                    [private] =&gt; 0
                    [disabled] =&gt; 0
                    [unique] =&gt; 0
                    [width] =&gt; 
                    [description] =&gt; 
                    [attributes] =&gt; Array
                        (
                        )

                    [conditional_component] =&gt; 
                    [conditional_operator] =&gt; =
                    [conditional_values] =&gt; 
                )

            [mandatory] =&gt; 1
            [weight] =&gt; 4
            [page_num] =&gt; 1
        )

    [#webform_private] =&gt; 0
    [#validated] =&gt; 1
    [#webform_validated] =&gt; 
)
```

Comment: "doesn't work"? Like, nothing happens? Or there is an error message? And could you maybe `dpr()` or `var_dump()` it so we could readily see what Webform is doing with email fields?

Comment: Yeah nothing happens. When you add autocomplete to a regular text field, a little image  appears on the right, which turns blue when it's sending / receiving queries. Applying the same rule to e-mail field doesn't show this. It's just a regular textfield that doesn't do anything. I'll get dpr(); added to the original post now.

Comment: Probably because webform adds it's own `#ajax` or makes this fieldset or other structure. That's why I asked for a dump.

Comment: What's the best way of getting the full dpr output on here. It's rather large!

Comment: @BeardedGeek Please don't add the full output from a `dpr()`...find the bits that are relevant to your question, and extract those

Comment: `dpr( $form['submitted']['name_of_authorising_manager'])` got large?! It's supposed to be just one field, right? Anyway, just paste it as a code block inside your question. Unless it's more than one field structure - in that case omit non-immediate children and leave it 1 or 2 levels deep.

Comment: Done and added to the first post.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use type of fields which are defined in [`hook_element_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7.x).

List all the type of elements using drush by:

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(module_invoke_all('element_info')));"
```

If you don't need to use Webform email, check the [Email field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module how it's implementing such element type. See: [Usage of email field with the form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/970068).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, Webform module provides it's own form elements for email and [some other kinds of data](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/webform_webform_component_info/7), and it simply does not implement autocomplete for them. You need to either [implement `hook_webform_component_info`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/webform_components/7) in your custom module to add this functionality, or fill a feature request on webform's issue queue.

Comment: I'm not sure on how I would use that hook to do it, so I've submitted a feature request within webform's issue queue - https://drupal.org/node/2070825